# How to show multiple phone numbers if exists in CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore, cncontactpicker

in my app I am using `CNContactPickerViewController` for getting contacts. User can select multiple contacts so I implemented following delegate methods.

```
 func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
        var tempContacts = [Contact]()
        contacts.forEach { (contact) in
            if let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first {
                let contact = Contact(name: "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)" , phoneNumber: "\(phoneNumber.value.stringValue)")
                tempContacts.append(contact)
            }
        }
        selectedContacts = tempContacts
        _ = Contact.save(contacts: selectedContacts)
    }
    func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
        print("Cancel contact picker")
    }
```

However, some users are complaining about not able to see and select if contact has more than one phone number. Is it possible to show contacts that have multiple numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You're only using the first phone number of a contact:

```
if let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first {
    let contact = Contact(name: "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)" , phoneNumber: "\(phoneNumber.value.stringValue)")
    tempContacts.append(contact)
}
```

What if you map all the phone numbers to an array of contacts using the `map` method:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    var tempContacts = [Contact]()
    contacts.forEach { (contact) in
        let contactPhoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers.map { Contact(name: "\($0.givenName) \($0.familyName)" , phoneNumber: "\($0.value.stringValue)") }
        tempContacts.append(contentsOf: contactPhoneNumbers)
    }
    selectedContacts = tempContacts
    _ = Contact.save(contacts: selectedContacts)
}
```

Comment: I already thought to add multiple phone numbers if it's exist but I would like to show the user while selecting on the list.